# Bankruptcy Chapter 8

Tags: united-states, business, bankruptcy

Why there is no chapter 8 bankruptcy?

I am a novice in law with no background in legal studies, but in business news, companies file for chapter 7 or chapter 11 bankruptcy. I am wondering what are these chapters and what is chapter 8, why only chapter 7 and 11 deals with business bankruptcy?

Comment: Looking at https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/11 (click the Notes tab), it says that Chapter 8 (sections 800-899) was repealed, but doesn't say when or what it previously contained.  But as of now, USC Title 11 has no Chapter 8 at all.

Comment: Thank you Nate. These repeal of laws are done by the President or Congressmen(also including the SC ruling)?

Comment: Repealing a law works exactly the same way as passing a new one: both houses of Congress pass a bill, and either the President signs it, or the President vetoes it and Congress can try to override the veto.  Often there will be a single bill that repeals existing law and creates something new to replace it.

Comment: Okay, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The law which handles this is [Title 11 of the United States Code](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/11), which has had several chapters repealed so there is no Chapter 8.

The Title covers all manner of bankruptcy, including liquidation (where the entity ceases to exist as a trading entity), which is Chapter 7, and reorganization (where the entity gains protection from their creditors while trying to re-organize into a profitable trading entity), which is Chapter 11.  Other chapters deal with things such as estates etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick help.